# How to avoid Opera required field tooltip bug when using @font-face?

Tags: css, opera, font-face

I believe this is an Opera bug, so let me show you what's wrong first. I use a custom @font-face font throughout the whole website. It works fine everywhere. Except Opera's required tooltip which doesn't have any text displayed when using custom font.

This is how the tooltip looks like when using @font-face for the whole website content:
[image]

This is how it should look like:
[image]

So, this is my @font-face definition:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans';
    src: url('/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#OpenSansRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And this is how I set to the whole site's contents:

```
body, button, input, select, textarea {
    color: #454545;
    font: normal normal 12px/15px "OpenSans", "Lucida Grande", "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}
```

**So, how do I avoid this?** I don't want to sacrifice the custom font just for this bug. I don't believe there is a selector for the tooltip, is there?

Comment: I've had tooltip issues in the past and found that as of yet there is no selector for them. Hopefully this will change soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Diggersworld is correct is saying that this is a Opera problem.  I work with Opera often and use [jQuerytools](http://jquerytools.org/)(or similar tooltip script) to bypass this inconsistency in Opera.

You should be able to use customized html to create the tooltip without sacrificing the font of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a known Opera bug.

For the most part, Opera inherits font styling from whatever is applied to the input element. `input{font-size:2em;}` for example, will make the error message 2em as well. But, as you've found, there is a bug when using @font-face.

The only way around it -- and it isn't much of a way -- is to style your form fields using a system font instead.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same bug. There is an ugly hack if you serve your pages as *.php i added this on top of the page:

```
<?php $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; $opera = false; if(preg_match('/Opera/',$u_agent)){$opera = true;}?>
```

and then inside the form (served as echo):

```
echo "<input type='text' name='required_field1' title='This field is required.'";if($opera == false){echo "required";}echo" />";
```

Than the only thing left is to have a fallback for browsers without understanding 'required' (and opera) by something like this:

```
if($_POST['required_field1'] == NULL && $_POST['required_field2'] == NULL){echo "Please fill out all of the form fields.";}
```

ALTERNATIVE
My server just served the default values while using get_browser()-function but you could try also something like this as an alternative instead for the whole thing on top of the page:

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
```

and than instead of `"if ($opera == false)"` you would type:

```
if ($browser[browser] != 'Opera')
```

which would be a bit shorter but isn't tested properly ;)

Comment: This is overkill for what is a client-side problem.